# Problems to get the roles after upgrade keycloak Version 20.0.3

Tags: java, spring, keycloak

I upgraded from keycloak 18 to 20.0.3.
But now I'm having trouble retrieving roles.

The Error: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found

This is what i'm trying to do...

`RealmResource realmResource = KeycloakHelper.getRealmResource(connectionParameters);`
in connectionParameters is the keycloakServerUrl, keycloakServerRealm, user and password

`representation = realmResource.roles().get("roleName").toRepresentation();`

but the `realmResource.roles().get("roleName").toRepresentation()` throws a `javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found` error

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. You may no longer use /auth in version 20.0.3